# V brake lever with calipers

Tags: fixed-gear, brake-levers

I am converting an old road bike to fixed gear with brakes. I am opting for long reach calipers as the brake reach is 70mm. As i am going to put a flat handlebar I am thinking of buying brake lever but can't figure out should go for v brakes lever or not.

Will V-brake lever work with long reach calipers?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

MTB vee brakes have a different pull ratio than road caliper pull ratio.

They make specific levers for each.

I've used normal mtb vee levers on road bikes before and it was fine, when I used the brakes, it just felt like it stopped with small amounts of movement of the lever. So modulation wasn't great. But it worked.

Alternatively, you could use "cross top" levers which should work better than normal MTB levers.

Cross top levers, used a lot in CX and touring bikes. [image: Cross top levers, used a lot in CX and touring bikes.]

Comment: I am thinking of buying https://www.decathlon.in/p/6318775/bikes-brakes-and-brake-pads/v-brake-type-brake-levers-x2

Comment: With these calipers http://www.tektro.com/mobile/products.php?p=45       will these work with each other

Comment: They will work as I said in the answer. Will work, not great. But will work. I would personally find road specific levers. But it's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are buying new parts anyway why not just get the correct levers. We are talking about brakes and it is important that they work at their best not pretty good. The levers you need will be described as cantilever brake compatible. There are even models with two cable anchor points so they can be used with both canti or linear pull.